# Log Analytics with Python

Tags: python, transactionloganalysis

I have the below text file. It's a log file. However, when i read it using Python, it sees it as one single line but inside the line, there are several transactions. I want to be able to read the individual lines within that 'Line'. Below is the text file:

```
[30-Apr-2020] [23:52:13:093] [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '217' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] [27263170] [172.16.211.13][a70ce98f-7931-482a-8418-a4ccb4f43aaa][com.intellectdesign.cib.viewdefinition.hal.IntegratorListViewInstruction][INFO] {Entered into Method: {TOTAL_NUM_RECORDS=0, ALL_RECORDS=[{OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-20 14:21:53.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRMOB, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=254723237762, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=          55,000, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Safaricom M-Pesa B2C, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB5945920, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-20 13:22:47.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRMOB, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=254723237762, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=           5,000, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Safaricom M-Pesa B2C, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB592AE20, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-20 13:16:22.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRMOB, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=0703761794, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=           4,000, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Safaricom M-Pesa B2C, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB5924E20, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-18 14:43:54.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRMOB, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=0703761794, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=           3,600, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Safaricom M-Pesa B2C, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB5790A20, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-18 14:41:55.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=PESAF, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=KCB 1169902251, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=          55,000, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Pesalink, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB5790320, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-17 17:28:06.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=PESAF, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=KCB 1169902251, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=         200,000, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Pesalink, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB55EDE20, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-17 08:48:08.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRIFT, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=01108076490100, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=           5,126, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Internal Funds Transfer, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB5540820, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-17 04:22:26.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRMOB, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=254723237762, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=          25,000, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Safaricom M-Pesa B2C, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB552B020, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-17 04:20:34.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRIFT, OD_STATUS=AH, BENE_ACC_NO=01108076490100, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=         320,400, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Internal Funds Transfer, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB552A420, TRANSACTION_STATUS=success}, {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-17 04:18:32.0, OD_FUNCTION_ID=CRIFT, OD_STATUS=RH, BENE_ACC_NO=01108076490100, OD_TXN_CY=KES, OD_AMOUNT=         330,866, TRANTYPEID=1, MODULE_DESCRIPTION=Internal Funds Transfer, OD_REF_NO=AAAAB5529820, TRANSACTION_STATUS=failed}], ENCODE_RESPONSE_IND=true, JSON_DATA={}}}
```

I want to be able to separate the lines at {OD_MAKER_DATE=2020-04-17 04:20:34.0 ................}.

My python code is:

```
#Loading libraries
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
filename = r'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\test.txt'  

with open(filename) as fn:  
   ln = fn.readline()
   lncnt = 1
   while ln:
       print("Line {}: {}".format(lncnt, ln.strip()))
       ln = fn.readline()
       lncnt += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to separate a string by another string, you use the .split() method.

```
string = 'ABC splithere XYZ splithere COOL'
parts  = string.split('splithere')
print(parts)
```

If you want some more complicated string splitting or string matching you need to use the "re" python module.